# HTML a pdf con django

Tags: html, python, django, pdf

Estoy iniciando en django; me encuentro trabajando con html y quisiera convertir a pdf. Tengo esta vista que obtiene datos mediante el id de un usuario registrado en mi BD:

```
def contrato(request, id):
    return render(request,'contrato\contrato.html', {'asociado': get_queryset(id)})
```

Esto me renderiza el siguiente html, es algo sencillo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CPS</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contrato de Prestación de Servicios</h1>
        <div>         
            <ul>
                {% for dato in asociado %}
                <li>Función/Título: {{ dato.job_title }}</li>
                <li>nombre completo: {{ dato.first_name }} {{ dato.last_name }}</li>
                <li>Email: {{ dato.email }}</li>
                <li>RFC: {{ dato.rfc }}</li>
                <li>CURP: {{ dato.curp }}</li>
                <li>Clabe: {{ dato.interbank_key }}</li>
                <li>País:  {{ dato.country }}</li>
                <li>Status:  {{ dato.status }}</li>
                <li>Creado: {{dato.created}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Me gustaría poder convertir este html ya con la información registrada a pdf para poder descargarlo, sin embargo, lo que he logrado es que sólo me genere o un pdf vacío sin los datos de la persona que quiero o un pdf con solamente el encabezado H1.

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien quieres crear un PDF apartir un una plantilla HTML en Django.

Hay una libreria que se llama [WeasyPrint](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/) que te seria de ayuda te paso un ejemplo de codigo.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from weasyprint import HTML
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration

def export_pdf(request):
    context = {}
    html = render_to_string("report/report-pdf.html", context)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; report.pdf"

    font_config = FontConfiguration()
    HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, font_config=font_config)

    return response
```

link del ejemplo https://www.codigojs.com/django-framework/generar-un-pdf-con-django/